# How to Make a Plane Object Move Individual Vertex's in the Third Dimension

Tags: modeling, transforms

I'm learning how to use blender, and have been watching this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QT1GNMevfc&t=67s) to make a man for a game. Now this video is fairly outdated but I've been able to do everything he has so far (with the exception of putting the reference photo as a background, I instead put it as an actual 2D object), but at 11:00 he begins to take the plane that we used and pull it forwards into the 3rd direction. I can't figure out how he did this and after an hour or so and lots of research that showed nothing I am only able to move it in 2 dimensions up/down and left/right. How do you move it backwards and forwards?

Comment: It looks like the "depth" axis (the one you "pull out" on) is the Y axis in your example video, so select your faces/edges/verts (which ever one) and either  move it (G) or extrude it (E) along the Y axis. (Example G+Y to move on Y axis)

Comment: The use of reference images changed quite drastically between Blender versions 2.7x and 2.8/9. There's quite a good tutorial on setting them up [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRUDeiuWnoM).